# Anchor image to a corner

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml

I'm trying to anchor an image to the lower left corner of my application window, but I can't really figure out how to do it. Any help appreciated!

```
ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 800
height: 1280

Rectangle {
    //color: "#212126"
    color: "black"
    anchors.fill: parent
    Image {
        id: qtLogo
        source: "myimage.jpg"
        width: parent.width/3
        height: parent.height/3
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you actually try to search for the answer? It's the second result of a Google search for "anchor qml": http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html

Answer (score 1):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html

use `background-position` see the the Qt stylesheet reference above for an example

Comment: I tried this:  QFrame {
     background: url(:/images/footer.png);
     background-position: bottom left;
 }
But it's not valid QML code it seems.